# 2nd Order Differential Equation Limits

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limits, quadratics

Consider the differential equation
  $$ay′′ + by′ + cy = g(t)$$
where $a > 0$, $c > 0$, and $g(t)$ is a continuous function on $\mathbb R$.

(a) If $y(t)$ is a solution of the above equation with $b > 0$ and $g(t) = 0$, show that $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}=0$.

(b) Is the result in (a) true, if $b = 0$?

(c) If $g (t) = d$ and $b > 0$, show that $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}=\frac{d}{c}$
for every solution $y(t)$ to the above equation.

I am under the impression that I need to use the characteristic equation in parts a and b to show that its' roots are negative, thus $y=e^{-xt}$ is a solution to the equation in one form or the other. This would lead to the limit approaching zero.

Part C is the main difficulty, I believe it involves utilizing the form of "variation of parameters", but I am not sure what to do with that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If $g(t)=d$ (constant), show that all solution of $L[y] \to \frac{d}{c}$ when $t \to \infty$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1651488/if-gt-d-constant-show-that-all-solution-of-ly-to-fracdc-when-t)

Comment: You can do the following: you change $t = 1/x$, so now your limit $t \lim \infnty$ reads $x \lim 0$. You divide the equation such that the term $y(x)/x$ appears in it. Now, yo apply Cauchy residue theorem and you will get $y(x=0)=y(t \lim \infty)$ in it and some other terms. These other terms, zero or not, will give you all the relations you are after.

Comment: PS: sorry for math editing in previous post. I left the editor open and got called in a meeting. After, it was impossible to edit the comment.